# C++ Debugging approaches for code that is compiled in release mode and called from Python

Tags: python, c++, debugging, release

I have the following situation:

I have the C++ code that is used from Python through bindings.

This code does processing of incoming network packages and decoding them (it's audio and video packets). So the performance is essential and trying to compile it in debug mode renders it unusable.

My question is what are the good practices to approach debugging in this scenario?

Obviously, I can do print debugging and a lot of logging, and that's what I do right now. 
But I'm wondering whether there are approaches or tools that can simplify my life.
Thank you!

Working environment: Linux, GCC 4.9, python2.7.